# Parametric curves - derivate at the given point (tangent line)

Tags: derivatives, tangent-line

$x(t) = t^2, $
$y(t) = t^5$

I want to find derivate at point $(0,0$) and tangent line if derivate exists.

I did it following way:

$\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{5}{2}t^3$ if i put in $t=0$ i will get $0$ - does it mean that derivate at $(0,0)$ exists and tangent line is $y=0$?

Comment: did you mean $x(t) = ^2 , y(t) = t^5$?

Comment: yes, edited now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a graph of your given curve and its derivative.
[image] At $t =0$ the derivative does not exist as the left hand derivative and the right hand derivative do not match.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:we have $$\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{5t^4}{2t}=\frac{5}{2}t^3$$

Comment: Could you edit it to $t^3$?

Comment: Thank you for your hint!

Comment: Well, that's the thing I already got.. I just wonder that if I put $0$ for $t$ will that be the derivate at point $(0,0)$ and does it mean that derivate exists (tangen line will exist then too)?

Comment: The derivative at this point is zero, it can be a extrem point or a horizontal turning point or does not exist.( for $t=0$ exists no derivative)

Answer (score 0):

You’ve simplified the expression for ${dy\over dx}$ too soon. In full, it’s ${5t^4\over2t}$. This is equal to $\frac52t^3$ *unless* $t=0$, where the expression is undefined. That’s exactly the situation at $(0,0)$, so you can’t use the value of $\frac52t^2=0$ directly.